# Desenvolver template padrão Razor - ASPNET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou com um projeto ASPNET MVC5 utilizando C# que, por definição de projeto foi-se convencionado que o Layout da estrutura das páginas iria ficar armazenado no Banco de Dados.

Dentro da minha _ViewStart seria referenciado meu _Layouts.cshtml que seria o conteúdo comum das páginas. Até ai tudo bem, o problema é que o conteúdo que seria da estrutura do site seria buscado do banco de dados, com todos os elementos HTML e Razor, e renderizados na tela. Para HTML simples (sem nenhum Razor) isso iria funcionar tranquilamente com algumas das alternativas a seguir (código da view _layouts.cshtml onde ConteudoHTML seria buscado do banco e retornado pelo controller):

- @ViewBag.ConteudoHTML ou @Html.Raw(ViewBag.ConteudoHTML.ToString())
- ou mesmo criando um Helper e referenciando na view: @MeuHelper.Template(ViewBag.ConteudoHTML.ToString())

O problema é que armazeno no banco de dados a estrutura que já contem minhas referências a Models, ViewBag, Helpers, etc. Quando renderiza o navegador não reconhece os elementos do Razor (além disso, na minha View o compilador não executa sem o RenderBody() explicito lá, mesmo que eu já tenha inserido ele junto ao registro do banco).

Pesquisei aqui e vi uma possível solução utilizando RazorEngine, porém nos meus testes aqui ele não esta funcionando de nenhuma maneira para HTML's mais complexos (envolvendo Custom Helpers por exemplo).

Alguém poderia me ajudar com alguma ideia de recurso para implementar?

Exemplo dos conteúdos:
- HTML armazenado no banco

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="@ViewBag.MetaDescription" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="@ViewBag.MetaKeywords" />   
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>                
    <!--[if IE]><link rel="shortcut icon" href="~/css/images/favicon.ico"><![endif]-->
    <link rel="icon" href="@Url.Content("~/css/images/favicon.png")" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/css/bootstrap.min.css")" />
    @RenderSection("Css", required: false)
</head>

<body>
    @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

-- Código no controler

```
public virtual ActionResult Index()    
{
    ViewBag.ConteudoHTML = "";//HTML vindo do banco, html acima
    ViewBag.Title = "Meu título";
    ViewBag.MetaDescription = "Description";
    ViewBag.MetaKeywords = "Keywords";

    return View();
}
```

-- Código da view (_Layouts.cshtml)

```
@ViewBag.ConteudoHTML
```

OBS: como já tentei implementar isso de diversas formas não tem como colocar todas soluções que tentei, mas não divergem muito dessa ai.

Comment: sengundo o ScottGu é possivel carregar as Views de qual quer lugar.

Porém é um pouco mais complicado que apenas jogar uma String na View(*.cshtml)

Para tal, você precisar registrar uma VirtualPathProvider.
Abaixo segue um bom tutorial de como faze-lo:
http://www.umbraworks.net/bl0g/rebuildall/2009/11/17/ASP_NET_MVC_and_virtual_views

Comment: Eu tentei trabalhar sobrescrevendo esse VirtualPathProvider, mas ao fazer uma prova de conceito ele não teve o funcionamento esperado. Estou achando que é a versão do ASPNET MVC. De qualquer forma os tutoriais que eu segui são diferentes desse ai, vou tentar esse e posto o resultado.

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi o arquivo não fica em disco: fica em banco. O design do Lenard Gunda resolve parcialmente seu problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver utilizando o VirtualPathProvider sobrescrito.

Foi útil a contribuição do TobyMosque através do link http://www.umbraworks.net/bl0g/rebuildall/2009/11/17/ASP_NET_MVC_and_virtual_views.